# FOREIGN KEY Constraint suggestions

Tags: sql

My Problem is that in order to update my database, I must have my timezone drop down box re-selected every time I wish to update due to a constraint key.

I'm dealing with two tables...

City table constraints the foreign key constraint which is IDTimeZone

time_zone table contains the primary key which is IDTimeZone

What I am trying to figure out how to do is basically have my plugin not depend on if the user has chosen a timezone or not in order to update that destination. Unfortunately I am not in control of whether the IDTimeZone is a constraint or not.

```
// city timezone
$time_zone = isset($_POST['tz']) ? $_POST['tz'] : 0;
if ($time_zone <> 0) {
$errorcode = 0;
$strmsg = "";
$sql="SELECT * from time_zone ORDER BY NAME;";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$cont=mysql_num_rows($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $chtml = '<select name="tz" id="tz"><option value="0">--Select time zone--   </option>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $chtml .= '<option value="'.$row['IDTimeZone'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
    }
    $chtml .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$chtml));
}else{
    $errorcode = 1;
    $strmsg = '<font style="color:#F00;">No States available</font>';
    echo json_encode(array("errorcode"=>$errorcode,"chtml"=>$strmsg));
}
}
```

and here is my update code for sql...

```
$SQL = "UPDATE city SET description='$description',page_title='$pagetitle',page_tags='$metakey', page_description_tag='$metadescription',
    is_active='$active',population='$pop', county='$county', IDTimeZone='$tz', elevation='$ele', peak_season='$ps', /* sunrise*/ srise_jan='$srjan',srise_feb='$srfeb',srise_mar='$srmarch',srise_apr='$srapril',srise_may='$srmay',srise_jun='$srjune',
    srise_jul='$srjuly', srise_aug='$sraug', srise_sep='$srsept', srise_oct='$sroct', srise_nov='$srnov', srise_dec='$srdec',/*Sun Set */ sset_jan='$ssjan',
    sset_feb='$ssfeb',sset_mar='$ssmarch',sset_apr='$ssapril',sset_may='$ssmay',sset_jun='$ssjune', sset_jul='$ssjuly', sset_aug='$ssaug',
    sset_sep='$sssept', sset_oct='$ssoct', sset_nov='$ssnov', sset_dec='$ssdec',/*Temp*/temp_jan='$tjan',temp_feb='$tfeb',temp_mar='$tmarch',temp_apr='$tapril',temp_may='$tmay',temp_jun='$tjune',
    temp_jul='$tjuly', temp_aug='$taug', temp_sep='$tsept', temp_oct='$toct', temp_nov='$tnov', temp_dec='$tdec',/*Precip */precip_jan='$pjan',precip_feb='$pfeb',precip_mar='$pmarch',precip_apr='$papril',precip_may='$pmay',precip_jun='$pjune',
    precip_jul='$pjuly', precip_aug='$paug', precip_sep='$psept', precip_oct='$poct', precip_nov='$pnov', precip_dec='$pdec'
     WHERE IDCity ='$ID'";
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick in the Sql Server world that I'm sure easily translates to other Sql environments is to test for a value in the update, and if null, just use the existing value.

```
UPDATE city
SET
Population = @population --sql server syntax for parameters,
...--other columns
IDTimeZone = Case When @IDTimeZone IS NULL Then IDTimeZone Else @IDTImeZone End,
...--other columns
WHERE
IDCity = @IDCity
```

The gist of it is pretty simple...is there a value? if yes, set it...otherwise, simply set it to whatever the previous value is in the table, effectively not changing that column value.

Answer (score 0):

My first question to you would be: can't you cache the time zone data somewhere rather than query it every time?

Ok, that out of the way, if I understand your question, you want to issue the update though the user may not have selected a timezone. As far as the database is concerned, the foreign key field of your CITY table will accept a NULL value unless the database designer has deliberately defined the field as NOT NULL -- which is a possibility.

But...you are executing an Update statement, so the city record must already exist. My second question to you would be: why aren't you reading in the existing record and pre-loading the timezone drop down with the value that's already there (along with sunrise, sunset and all that other stuff)? So whether the user changes it or leaves it alone, you're fine.

Your only problem would be when inserting a new city record and the user has not selected a time zone and the timezone field has been declared NOT NULL. Well, then tell the user that the time zone is required information and refuse to proceed until they select something.

Have I missed something?